# How to get Session obj value on client side from server js?

Tags: meteor

Hi as i mensioned above how to get the session variable from server to client js using meteor below placed the code verify and give me a sugession.In the bellow code how to get the **ltest** on client JS.

validation.Js:

```
 Meteor.methods({
        signupUser: function signupUser(rawData){
            console.log("rawData :: "+rawData);
            Mesosphere.signupForm.validate(rawData, function(errors, exmp){
                if(!errors){
                    console.log("No Errors Found");
                    var username = '';
                    var password = '';
                    console.log(rawData.length + ">>>>>>>");
                    for(var i = 0;i < rawData.length ; i++)
                    {
                        var obj = rawData[i];
                        if(i == 0)
                        {
                            username = rawData[i].value;
                            console.log(rawData[i].value + ">>>>>>>" + obj.value);
                        }
                        else(i == 1)
                        {
                            password = rawData[i].value;
                        }
                    }
                    var  obj = Meteor.call('ltest', username,password);
                    console.log("**********************"+obj);  
                    //Session.set('q', obj);

                    //Do what you want with the validated data.
                }else{
                    _(errors).each( function( value, key ) {
                        console.log("signupUser >> "+key+": "+value.message);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: `Session` is not available on on server side, you must be getting error. Do you want to return some value to client from this meteor method?

Comment: I know but how to get the obj of ltest from server to client in the above code .@ajduke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You need to use Future for this to return data from async call in method.

Second, Looks like you are trying to do code re-use with calling another meteor method.

IMO, you should not call the meteor method from another meteor method, which will create the another callback for getting results, which is added overhead and also make code unreadable. You should basically create the  common function and try calling it from both Meteor method.

Following is listing, which should work

```
// define this future at top of file 
Future = Npm.require("fibers/future")

 Meteor.methods({
        signupUser: function signupUser(rawData){
            console.log("rawData :: "+rawData);
            future = new Future()
            Mesosphere.signupForm.validate(rawData, function(errors, exmp){
                if(!errors){
                    console.log("No Errors Found");
                    var username = '';
                    var password = '';
                    console.log(rawData.length + ">>>>>>>");
                    for(var i = 0;i < rawData.length ; i++)
                    {
                        var obj = rawData[i];
                        if(i == 0)
                        {
                            username = rawData[i].value;
                            console.log(rawData[i].value + ">>>>>>>" + obj.value);
                        }
                        else(i == 1)
                        {
                            password = rawData[i].value;
                        }
                    }
                    //var  obj = Meteor.call('ltest', username,password);
                    // replace above call to common method as described above 
                     obj = common_ltest(username, password);
                    console.log("**********************"+obj);                          
                    future['return'](obj);
                }else{
                    _(errors).each( function( value, key ) {
                        console.log("signupUser >> "+key+": "+value.message);
                    });
                     // assuming some error here, return null to client 
                      future['return'](null);
                }
            });
          // **note that, this important**
          return future.wait()
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps